# what is the c# equivalent of Calendar in java?

Tags: c#, java, calendar

I am converting Java to C# and need to convert code involving Calendar:

```
Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append((rightNow.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1));
sb.append(rightNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
sb.append(rightNow.get(Calendar.YEAR)).substring(2);
sb.append(rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
sb.append(rightNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

**MORE EDIT** As there are two possible approaches (System.DateTime and Calendar) which should I use? (I recall problems in the Java universe here)

**SUMMARY of RESPONSES** For simple uses System.DateTime is appropriate and does not have the problems of Java's Date. There should be a single call in case the date ticks forward between calls.

Comment: System.DateTime should do it.

Comment: I hope there is none.  What I mean is that whatever the alternative it must be better than the **horrible** Calendar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`System.DateTime`](http://www.csharpfriends.com/demos/system.datetime.aspx) structure is what you're looking for.

#### Preferred Way:

```
sb.Append(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).ToString("MMddyyHHmm"));
```

As Joel Coehoorn points out, you could condense that code down to one line. I had become so engorged on the implementation, I didn't see what you were actually trying to do -- luckily Joel pointed it out.

That will roll all of those up into one call. Pretty nifty.

#### Direct Translation (Not recommended):

To translate your Java code into C#, you'd do something like the following:

```
string year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
sb.Append(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1));
sb.Append(DateTime.Now.Day);
sb.Append(year.Substring(2));
sb.Append(DateTime.Now.Hour);
sb.Append(DateTime.Now.Minute);
```

You can copy/paste this C# code to see:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
sb.Append(String.Format("Next Month is: {0} \n ",DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1)));
sb.Append(String.Format("Day is {0}\n ", DateTime.Now.Day));
sb.Append(String.Format("Year is {0}\n ", year.Substring(2)));
sb.Append(String.Format("The Hour is {0}\n ", DateTime.Now.Hour)); //getting late
sb.Append(String.Format("The Minute is {0}\n ", DateTime.Now.Minute));
```

#### Regarding Java issues with DateTime

The `DateTime` structure doesn't have the same issues that Java had with their date implementation; so you shouldn't have the same problems that plagued the Java world.

#### Other Methods

As [another user pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569272/what-is-the-c-equivalent-of-calendar-in-java/1569286#1569286), you can use the [`System.Globalization.Calendar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar%28VS.71%29.aspx) class as well.  I get along just fine with the `DateTime` struct, and it's a little lighter-weight than the Calendar class, but they both can be used. If you're going to jump around date and calendar implemenations, then go with the `Calendar` class; if you're going to stick with one implementation of dates, then the `DateTime` `struct` is just fine.

Comment: Or, even better, condense all that to just DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).ToString("MMddyyHHmm")

Comment: You should avoid repeatedly calling DateTime.Now and then playing with the date parts; what if the clock ticks over midnight between getting DateTime.Now.Day and DateTime.Now.Hour?

Comment: +1, very good point, Roger. In that vein I'll bump the 'update' up to the top as the 'preferred way' to do it.

Answer (score 6):

```
System.DateTime
```

Like:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime tommorowsTomorrow = now.AddDays(2);
```

And so on.

Answer (score 2):

There's also [Calendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar%28VS.71%29.aspx).